# Need FULL transparency of ".png" file format

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt5, transparent, alpha-transparency

I want a floating round button (no window-frame + no title bar + transparency) in my Python-project. For this I created a round button in GIMP (with transparency around the button). I am a beginner in GUI-programming therefore I will explain you all the steps I already tried so far:

1. First try: I tried to use Tkinter with this attributes:

   self.configure(background='black')

   self.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

   self.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', 'black')

This was a little success for me but I didn't like the jagged edges around:
the jagged edges were best visible on white backgrounds:
[image: the jagged edges were best visible on white backgrounds]

2. Second try: This time I used PyQt5 and at first glance everything was perfect and I used these settings:

   ```
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
   ```

But a closer look gave me this:

partly transparent grey/white background:
[image: partly transparent grey/white background]

Now I need advice from an expert because I could not find any helpful tutorial or documentation for this problem.

Comment: Did you try `canvas.fill(Qt.transparent)` ?

Comment: Hi Atlas, I get this error: 'AttributeError: 'Canvas' object has no attribute 'fill''..

Comment: That seems like the original image you're using doesn't use a full transparency, so go back and fix the alpha layer.

Comment: Hi musicamante, I have to admit this is something I didn't check because in GIMP it is showing transparency. But you are right what if there is not 100% transparency.. That would be great.. I will check this now..

Comment: Musicamante I have to thank you so much!!! That was a fantastic idea! now it's 100% transparent.. Again thank you sooooo much, really good idea!